# Acrescentar <option> automatico cada mês que passa

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho um sistema de pagamento, que possui um select que exibe os meses desde que o sistema iniciou, segue codigo abaixo:

```
<select name="situacao">
   <option>Fevereiro/2018</option>
   <option>Janeiro/2018</option>
   <option>Dezembro/2017</option>
   <option>Novembro/2017</option>
</select>
```

O que eu preciso, é que quando inicie o próximo mês, no caso março, acrescente a opção de março automaticamente, e assim sucessivamente nos próximos meses.

Comment: Você pretende fazer isso com javascript? Porque isso pode dar problema caso o horário do computador esteja errado...

Comment: Cara, eu não faço ideia como faz, se da pra fazer em js pode ser, o site fica hospedado numa hospedagem, horario dela ta correto.

Comment: Serve em PHP? Dá pra fazer Armazenando os meses em um banco

Comment: Serve, se poder me ajudar

Comment: Da para fazer usando `JS` no lado do client, mas vale lembrar que o horário atual do computador do indivíduo influencia. Seria interessante criar   algo no lado do servidor. Se mesmo assim quiser, crio um exemplo de como funcionaria no lado do client

Comment: Cara não crie no JS. Como foi dito acima, o js fica na máquina client. Se o horário/data estiverem errados (o que pode acontecer facilmente) seu código não funcionará corretamente. Faça em uma linguagem server side. Muito mais seguro. PHP é um exemplo, mas tem muitas outras que pode utilizar, como: Python, C#, JS mesmo com Node, etc. Exemplos, já postaram e não devem ser problema. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como citei no comentário acima, aqui está uma solução do lado do `client`. Deixei comentários no código, caso tenha dúvidas pode perguntar.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var date = new Date(); //invoca o metodo Date
var mes = date.getMonth() +1;// pega o mes atual
var ano = date.getFullYear();

switch(mes) {//faz um switch para saber o dia e acrescentar o option de acordo
   case 1: criaOption('Janeiro')
      break;    
    case 2 : criaOption('Fevereiro')
    break;
    case 3 : criaOption('Março')
    break;
    case 4 : criaOption('Abril')
    break;
    case 5 : criaOption('Maio')
    break;
    case 6 : criaOption('Junho')
    break;
    case 7 : criaOption('Julho')
    break;
    case 8 : criaOption('Agosto')
    break;
    case 9 : criaOption('Setembro')
    break;
    case 10 : criaOption('Outubro')
    break;
    case 11 : criaOption('Novembro')
    break;
    case 12 : criaOption('Dezembro')
    break;
    
}
function criaOption(mes) {
  var opt = "<option value='"+mes+"'> "+mes+" / "+ano+" </option>"
  $('#dt').prepend(opt); //adiciona o mes no inicio, caso queira adiconar no final, use o append()   
    return opt;
}
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="dt">
  <option value="Dezembro"> Dezembro <option>
</select>
```

Comment: Editei o código, agora ele também captura e popula o ano na `option`.

Comment: Apesar de sua resposta está marcada como resolvida, ela não responde a pergunta. Seu código sempre vai ser "dezembro" > "mês atual". Se o mês atual for "Abril", seu código vai pular "Janeiro", "Fevereiro" e "Março".

Comment: @alxwca, desculpe, mas não entendi... Por qual motivo vai ser sempre 0? sendo que concatenei +1  na variável `mes`?

Comment: @JorgeMatheus foi mal, não tinha visto que tinha somado + 1 na variável.

Answer (score 2):

Esse código deve ajuda-lo, porém não esta elegante;

```js
var meses = new Array(12);
meses[0] = "Janeiro";
meses[1] = "Fevereiro";
meses[2] = "Março";
meses[3] = "Abril";
meses[4] = "Maio";
meses[5] = "Junho";
meses[6] = "Julho";
meses[7] = "Agosto";
meses[8] = "Setembro";
meses[9] = "Outubro";
meses[10] = "Novembro";
meses[11] = "Dezembro";


function carregaMes() {
  var data = new Date();
  var option = new Option();
  var tags = document.getElementById("meses");
  for (var i = 0; i <= data.getMonth(); i++) {
    var option = new Option(getMes(i), getMes(i));
    tags.add(option);
  }

}

function getMes(mes) {
  return this.meses[mes];
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="carregaMes()">
  <select id="meses" name="situacao">
         
      </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Se quiser setar o mês atual como **default** passe mais um parâmetro no construtor:

```
Option(getMes(i), getMes(i), getMes(data.getMonth()), getMes(data.getMonth()));
```

```js
var meses = new Array(12);
meses[0] = "Janeiro";
meses[1] = "Fevereiro";
meses[2] = "Março";
meses[3] = "Abril";
meses[4] = "Maio";
meses[5] = "Junho";
meses[6] = "Julho";
meses[7] = "Agosto";
meses[8] = "Setembro";
meses[9] = "Outubro";
meses[10] = "Novembro";
meses[11] = "Dezembro";


function carregaMes() {
  var data = new Date();
  var option = new Option();
  var tags = document.getElementById("meses");
  for (var i = 0; i <= data.getMonth(); i++) {
    var option = new Option(getMes(i), getMes(i), getMes(data.getMonth()), getMes(data.getMonth()));
    tags.add(option);
  }

}

function getMes(mes) {
  return this.meses[mes];
}
```

```html
<html>

<body onload="carregaMes()">
  <select id="meses" name="situacao">
         
      </select>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando a biblioteca [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com) é possível criar um select populando automaticamente todos os meses correntes de acordo com um range.

Assim o código fica limpo e de facil entendimento:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var start = moment().subtract(15, 'month'); // 15 messes anteriores ao atual.
  var end = moment();

  while(end >= start ) {
    var date = moment(end).format('MMMM/YYYY');
    
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = date;
    opt.innerHTML = date;
    
    $("#situacao").append(opt);
    
    end = moment(end).subtract(1, 'month');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/locale/pt-br.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="situacao"></select>
```

Comment: Legal não conhecia essa biblioteca